# Getting error when import instanceMethods function in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have created inside a file a function and export it using

```
export function foo(params...) {
 // do something
}
```

inside the initialization of the model I import the function in this way:

```
import { foo } from "../path/..."

instanceMethods: {
  foo: foo
}
```

the problem is the model is not initialized correctly. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is the model is not initialized correctly

The following code *works fine*.

export function foo(params...) {
 // do something
}

```
import { foo } from "./foo";

let instanceMethods = {
  foo: foo
};
```

Error is elsewhere. Perhaps you meant to use `=` and used `:`? Note that if you *don't use the variable it is erased form the output* ([ref](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html)).

@)-'--

Comment: Thank you basarat but instanceMethods is not a variable is a property of an object in sequelize. Take a look at the document http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models-definition/